# Reformat USB flash drive marked "Read Only"

Tags: partitioning, usb, read-only

I have a 32GB USB 3.0 Flash drive marked "Read Only". It is formatted FAT32. I don't know when it was formatted as such, and I need to reformat it.

I've attempted using Windows' Diskpart to mark it writeable, and removing the partition with Gparted, shred, and dosfsck.

The drive is roughly 2 years old and I've used it for a lot of Live USB boot disc creation, so it may be dying, although I thought flash drives were pretty resilient.

My next course of action will be to set up [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) and try to nuke it.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Every attempt I've made ended in an error akin to "Cannot write to this partition".

EDIT: If I remember correctly, I was transferring files to it when it suddenly locked up. So it may very well be done-for.

Comment: Try checking the drive's SMART data for clues. Perhaps you've exceeded its write endurance?

Comment: That's very possible. I have no idea how many times I reformatted it, and formatting must take its toll.

Comment: One short search in and I found [this thread, discussing USB mass storage failure and SMART systems](http://superuser.com/questions/102228/what-happens-when-a-flash-drive-wears-out). Apparently, there's no way to receive SMART data from flash drives.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that the drive is dead and locked down as a safety measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least a SanDisk USB flash device turns into persistent "Read only"-mode when it has detected internal trouble that might be a cause for imminent failure.

There is only one remedy:
Backup any data immediately and
Replace the flash memory as soon as possible to avoid trouble.

*I have experienced this just recently, the very first flash device EVER to die for me; a SanDisk Ultra, USB 3.0.*

Comment: Thanks for the wisdom. I've never had a USB flash device fail. Mine is a generic Microcenter drive. It's very possible that it's just dead. If I remember correctly, I was putting files on it when all of a sudden it locked up.